# How to extract data from two GQL classes?

Tags: sql, database, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I have the following 2 classes:

```
class UsersRSS(db.Model):
    userId = db.IntegerProperty()
    fileHash = db.StringProperty()
    added = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Files(db.Model):
    fileHash = db.StringProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    file = db.BlobProperty()
    added = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need to create a GQL query, which will return a data from both tables:

```
items = UsersRSS.gql("WHERE userId = :userId ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10", userId=user_id)
```

But each `item` besides `fileHash` and `added` fields, should contain fields from the second class - `title` and `file` (matching should be done by `fileHash` field).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to retrieve from Datastore different Kinds using the same *GQL Select statement*.

Another option would be using the [ReferenceProperty](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty) to create a many-to-one relationship between `UsersRSS` and `Files`, refactoring your code in this way:

```
class UsersRSS(db.Model):
    userId = db.IntegerProperty()
    file = db.ReferenceProperty(Files)
    added = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Files(db.Model):
    fileHash = db.StringProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    file = db.BlobProperty()
    added = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

items = UsersRSS.gql("WHERE userId = :userId ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10", userId=user_id)
```

In this way, the `Files` properties will be automatically dereferenced using the `item.file.title` dot notation:

```
for item in items:
    print item.UserID
    print item.Added
    print item.file.title #This costs an additional RPC call to Datastore
```

To save your App from the ReferenceProperty RPC overhead have a look to the evergreen article [ReferenceProperty prefetching](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine).

Comment: thanks! how to add `file` to `UsersRSS` with such approach? `file = Files(key_name="z"+self.request.get('hash')); file.put(); fileRecord = UsersRSS(); fileRecord.file = file; fileRecord.put()` is correct approach?

Comment: that's right, you probably forgot to set the `userId` to `fileRecord` before the `fileRecord.put()`.